# Maximizing profits in a guessing game with uneven rewards.

Tags: functions, inequality, game-theory

I have a relatively simple problem for which I require an intelligent solution.

There are two rooms, each with 15 vases inside (30 in total).

Room A has a diamond hidden in one of the vases. This diamond is worth 1*x*

In Room B, there is also a diamond hidden in one of the vases, but this diamond is worth 2*x*

I'm allowed to search first in Room A and then in Room B, but I can only search inside 15 vases in total.

What is the optimal way to distribute my searches so that I'm always maximizing my profits? How can I extend this problem to diamonds with even bigger value differences? (i.e. 1*x* vs 3*x*)

Best,
AC

Comment: If you find the diamond in room A, you no longer need to keep searching there. So you need to find the maximum of $f(n)$ where $n$ is the number of vases you search in room A before giving up and moving on to room B, and $f$ is the expected profit.

Comment: @BenjaminWang: That's overkill; see my answer.

Comment: Also , it depends on whether you want to have a sure profit or the best expectation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is wrong; I’ll be correcting it shortly.

---

“Maximizing my profits” isn’t a well-defined objective in a probabilistic setting. I’ll assume that you want to maximize the expected profit.

Every vase in room $A$ is worth an expected $\frac1{15}x$, whereas every vase in room $B$ is worth an expected $\frac2{15}x$, so you should search only in room $B$.

You might be confused by the prospect of finding the total value of $3x$ if you first search in room $A$, but by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity_of_expectation) you can’t gain from that in expectation. Whatever you gain in chances of finding the $1x$ diamond, you lose in chances of finding the $2x$ diamond, leading to a net loss in expectation.

This holds for any ratio of values of the diamonds.

Comment: "Every vase in room $A$ is worth an expected $1/15x$'... but the searching happens without replacement? I do agree that, in any case, the optimal strategy is to only search in Room $B$ (until you find the diamond there). The more vases turn out to be empty, the greater you chance of finding the diamond on the next search.

Comment: @afreelunch: "but the searching happens without replacement": That only changes the a posteriori probabilities after searching. A priori every vase is worth that amount. So a priori it's not worth planning to search $k$ vases in room $A$ worth $\frac{kx}{15}$, thereby giving up the chance to search the last $k$ vases in room $B$ worth $\frac{2kx}{15}$. We don't have to work out the more complicated a posteriori probabilities to conclude that.

Comment: I think you are considering a situation where we need to choose our search plan in advance, whereas I was imagining a situation where we can adapt our plan as information comes in. OP doesn't seem to clarify which one of these situations they are proposing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @afreelunch: No, I was assuming that the plan can be adapted. Whatever your plan is, however you adapt it, the expected value of it succeeding on the first $k$
vases in room $A$ can't be more than $\frac{kx}{15}$, and the opportunity cost due to vases you can no longer search in room $B$ is twice that. Certainly, by searching long enough in room $A$ you can create a situation where the *a posteriori* probability to find the $1x$ in room $A$ becomes so high that you should *then* continue searching in room $A$ instead of switching – but *a priori* that's a losing plan, adaptable or not.

Comment: I'd appreciate if the downvoter would provide reasons for the downvote so the answer could potentially be improved.

Comment: Intuitively, it makes sense to go for the second vase. Thanks for providing feedback to support what I thought.

Comment: And what if I get an extra third diamond that's worth 5 times the cheap one when I find both diamonds? How would this affect my search?

Comment: @TurleNOOB: That's quite a different question. It's discouraged to extend questions indefinitely in the comments, which are mainly for clarifying the questions and answers. If you ask that as a new question, you're welcome to notify me here and I'll try to answer there.

Comment: @joriki Thanks, I just posted a new question

Comment: @TurleNOOB: Thanks for the notification. I wrote an answer for the other question but then realized that I made a mistake and both that answer and this answer here are wrong. I need to get some other things done first but I'll be correcting both answers as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: @afreelunch: Your objection was justified; my reasoning was flawed. I'll be correcting the answer shortly.

Comment: @joriki To solve the problem rigorously, I think you may need to use backward induction/dynamic programming. [Though I wouldn't know how exactly to do that!]